# What is a safe way to interpolate Bash variables in a heredoc/multi-line variable without using eval?

Tags: bash, sed, eval, string-interpolation

So I had this crazy idea of embedding documentation into my scripts (which is nothing new, just new to me) and parsing them out with sed. I achieve this simply by commenting out a block of text with line delimiters, and then popping off the comment hash (on each line) when I print the string to stdout.

As an example, imagine a shell script `myscript.sh` like this:

```
   #!/usr/bin/env bash
   #---- doc:start ----#
   # Hello $User\n     
   # This is myscript.sh
   # ${red}This will be red!${eol}
   #---- doc:end   ----#
   printf "Hello, World!"
```

I have a sed script that grabs all content between the line dilemeters and puts that into a multiline variable `$doc`

With this variable, I want to interpolate any local variables (not necessarily exported variables), escape codes, term colors etc. and in looking at how to do this the only answer I've been able to find is using eval; here's a working example (using here strings):

```
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    line=$(eval "echo -e \"$line\""); 
    echo "$line"
  done  <<< "$doc"; # doc is a multiline variable
```

However if someone adds a `$(rm -rf ..)` to this block of text it would be executed; this patterns seems to allow for other *unsafe* scenarios.

Another approach I looked at was dynamically assigning variables using `printf -v line ...`, but cant manage to get the variable substitution working.

I'd like to achieve this in a Bash 3.2 context without having to install any additional tools or utilities; POSIX if at all possible, but Bashisms and common utilities are ok too. ***Want this to work on both Mac and Ubuntu***.

Maybe a regex for excluding anything that looks like executable commands (or otherwise super-escaping suspicious strings) would work too.

**Update:**
[Link to "working" code](https://gist.github.com/qodeninja/fbc44715e8771b0dc9b17ed3f441c86b)

Comment: BTW, note that `printf '%b\n' "$line"` is the POSIX-compliant alternative to `echo -e "$line"`. (Supporting `echo -e` as anything other than a command to print `-e` on output is *in and of itself* a POSIX violation, which is why even though bash chooses to be noncompliant by default, that's behavior dependent on runtime flags that can be disabled in favor of to-the-letter compliance, and thus shouldn't be relied on unless one fully controls the runtime environment).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for that, I'm constantly learning new patterns and I'll add this note to my arsenal =)

Comment: If you're curious for more details, see the APPLICATION USAGE section of https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html, and the excellent answer by Stephane Chazelas at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo

Comment: There are plenty of proper templating tools available without having to implement your own in pure shell.

Comment: @chepner it's simple enough that I can provide this functionality with a matter of one or two functions. It's really me being fancy and wanting to print colors. I could avoid this whole thing and just print plaintext.

Comment: That link to "working code" no more works. :-(

Answer (score 4):

Use [`envsubst`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/envsubst), from the GNU gettext package.

This requires only that you export the variables that should be open to being replaced. The below usage demonstrates temporarily promoting regular shell variables `red` and `eol` to be environment variables for the duration of a `envsubst` invocation:

```
red="$red" eol="$eol" envsubst <<<'EOF'
...${red}...${eol}...
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I did find `envsubst` but I decided against it because I didn't want to have to export anything. Any thoughts here?

Comment: The above intentionally demonstrates temporary exporting -- unless the set of variables you want to make available is too large to fit in the environment, it's typically a reasonable practice. Is there a specific practical concern at hand?

Comment: ah yes, missed that aspect, I'll give this a try. No, I'm not expecting a large set of variables, does this construct work with arrays too?

Comment: No, it doesn't -- arrays can't be placed in the environment, as environment arrays are NUL-terminated, but individual array elements can include anything but a NUL. (One could break them out into a series of individual regular environment variables, I suppose, with some work).

Comment: ah just realized another reason I went against this was because gettext/envsubst isnt available by default on OSX.

Comment: *nod*. Personally, I distribute software I built using [Nix](https://nixos.org), so anyone installing it gets the full dependency set, including on MacOS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200675/discussion-between-qodeninja-and-charles-duffy).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you really need is templating, rather than variable insertion. That said, you could do it explicitly variable-by-variable, which might provide extra security.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#---- doc:start ----#
# Hello $User\n
# This is myscript.sh
# ${red}This will be red!${eol}
#---- doc:end   ----#

# template replacemenmts
red=$'\e[31m'
norm=$'\e[m'
eol=$'\n'

# fetch and trim...
s=$(< $0)
s=${s%%#---- doc:end   ----#*}
s=${s##*#---- doc:start ----#}

# do substitutions
s=${s//\$User/$USER}
s=${s//\${red\}/$red}
s=${s//\${eol\}/$eol}
s=${s//\\n/$eol}

printf '%s\n%s' "$s" "$norm"
```

This avoids using `sed` or anything else which might behave differently from platform to platform. (`sed` is different between GNU, FreeBSD/MacOS and Solaris, for example.)

Just for something to think about, [here's an example](https://github.com/chvostek/shelltools/blob/master/sshswitch) of how I tend to embed documentation within bash scripts. (And yes, I use sed. :-) )